# Custom function not working with append method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a custom plugin ( from **[dotdotdot plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)**) used in my paragraph tag to make it ellipses if it overflows.

```
//ellipsis
        $(".custom").dotdotdot({
            /*  The HTML to add as ellipsis. */
            ellipsis    : '...',
            /*  Wrap-option fallback to 'letter' for long words */
            fallbackToLetter: true,
            /*  Optionally set a max-height, if null, the height will be measured. */
            height      : 40,
        });
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="drop">
        <p class="custom">
            Sub Division Title Sub Division Title Sub Division Title
        </p>
    </div>
</div>    

<a class="myBUtton"> click me</a>
```

For my project I have to append that .custom paragraph by clicking  .myBUtton. I used

```
$('.mainWrapper').on('click', '.myBUtton', function() {
            $(".drop").append('<p class="custom">Sub Division Title Sub Division Title Sub Division Title</p>');

        });
```

But if I append that paragraph with append method .dotdotdot function **not working**. without appending it's working but don't know why it's not working after append. Is there proper way to do that. May be I am doing wrong or missing anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`.myBUtton` is not inside `.mainWrapper`, and delegating the event to an element that is not a parent wont work as the event bubbles up the chain, not to sibling elements

```
$('.mainWrapper').on('click', '.myBUtton', function() {...
```

use an actual parent element, or the document

```
$(document).on('click', '.myBUtton', function() {
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the a.myButton is not part of .mainWrapper descendant, but is its sibling. This is the reason why you can't take advantage of event [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data).

You could do

```
$('.mainWrapper + .myBUtton').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).prev().append('<p class="custom">...text here...</p>');
});
```

OR using event delegation mechanism, you will have to attach the handler on the first common ancestor of all `.myButton` element then do what ever you'd like to inside this handler, like `$(this).prev().append('<p class="custom">...text here...</p>')` if its previous sibling stills a `.mainWrapper` ..

Answer (score 0):

put `$(".custom").dotdotdot({ //your code  })` inside a function and then call this function after the append event.